# POST command from view to controller not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Sometimes I don’t understand it at all. I just want to create a form where the user can enter one field, has to check a checkbox and only when the checkbox is checked the submit button works.
So my model looks like this:

```
[Table("ResetType")]
    public class ResetTypeModel
    {
        public bool IsTrue => true;

        [Display(Name = "Hostname")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(11, MinimumLength=11)]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$")]
        public string hostname {get; set;}

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("(True|true)")]
        [Display(Name = "I agree to the terms and conditions")]
        [Compare(nameof(IsTrue), ErrorMessage = "Please agree to Terms and Conditions")]
        public bool confirmed {get; set;}



    }
}
```

My controller calls the view:

```
public IActionResult Reset()
{
    return View();
}
```

And finally my current view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetDevice", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="media-body">
        <label for="resettype_name">Reset Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="ddl_resettype" ><option value="">Please select a Reset Type</option>
            <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
            <option value="Reset">Reset</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="media-body" >
                <label for="label_hostname">Hostname</label>

                <input class="form-control" name="hostname" id="hostname" />

                @Html.LabelFor(model=> model.hostname)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.hostname, new { @class = "form-control" })  
                @* <input asp-for="model.hostname" class="form-control" name="hostname" id="hostname" />   *@
                @* <input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" /> *@
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.confirmed)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.confirmed)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.confirmed)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.confirmed)


    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" />


}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.js" defer></script>
```

When I click on the submit button nothing is validated, but I think I had it once in the past couple of days with another view for some time, and secondly, more imprortant I get a 404 when I do the POST to the controller

```
[HttpPost]
//[Route("ResetDevice")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ResetDevice([FromBody] ResetTypeModel rtm){

    return RedirectToAction("Reset", "Test");
}
```

It is like that the method is not called.

What am I missing?

---

Update:

When I call it as ajax it is working, so what am I missing?

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ResetDevice',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                headers:
                {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                traditional: true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Successfully Imported");
                },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("jqXHR:" + jqXHR.status + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                }
```

---

Update:

Ok, I think I found the error. In the controller I used FromBody instead of FromForm

Comment: Instead of using IActionResult , try using ActionResult, at both GET and POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FromBody instead of FromForm in the controller. So it depends if you use javascript ajax or html.beginform